# Carga Multiples Archivos y Renombrarlos antes de guardarlos

Tags: java

Buen dia, mi problema es el siguiente, estoy cargando  múltiples archivos desde una app web el flujo esta correcto, solo que no he logrado que antes de guardarlos en el directorio de destino pueda renombrar los archivos a un estándar de nombre previamente definido.

```
public void guardarMultiplesArchivos(List<MultipartFile> files, String directorioRoot, BigDecimal subDirectorio) throws IOException {
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        guardarArchivo(file,directorioRoot, subDirectorio);
    }
}

private void guardarArchivo(MultipartFile file, String directorioRoot, BigDecimal subDirectorio) throws IOException {

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }


    if (!isValidoContentType(file.getContentType())) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Path path = Paths.get(directorioRoot+File.separator+subDirectorio+File.separator+file.getOriginalFilename());
    Files.write(path, bytes);
}
```

Gracias....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es simple. En el propio objeto MultipartFile tienes un método llamado "transferTo(File f)", por lo que tu código debería ser algo así:

```
File nuevoArchivo = new File(<ruta_donde_guardar><separador><nombre_archivo_segun_estandar>);
file.transferTo(nuevoArchivo);
```

Si, por lo que sea, esto no sirviese, creas el archivo destino de la misma manera, obtienes su outputstream y escribes los bytes del archivo recibido en él:

```
File nuevoArchivo = new File(<ruta_donde_guardar><separador><nombre_archivo_segun_estandar>);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(nuevoArchivo);
outStream.write(file.getBytes());
```

Espero serte de ayuda.